# Creating an argument handler for managing and parsing command arguments

Tags: java, generics, arguments

For an implementation of a command system, I wanted users to be able to denote a class[] of types that they want as their command arguments, and have a method accepting those types that they can utilize having the arguments pre-parsed.

Ex.

Player wants to create an statistics command that lists player statistics.
The command would have syntax /info PLAYER_NAME STATISTIC_NAME

On the code end, I want the user to be able to extend my Command class and have access to a method

```
public void resolve(S arg1, T arg2);
```

Here we must now have generics  which is a problem if I have a long list or arguments. Also, S and T must implement some interface so they can be converted from String to their type. Also there is no class array, only a various number of overloaded methods that doesn't ensure 100% compatability For example what if I want an Integer argument, I can't just modify Integer to help me out here. My attempted solution was to create an argument wrapper (ArgType) and have S and T extend ArgType, this works fine until I tried to make ArgType a pseudo singleton by using a Manager to store Class to instance. This was a problem because

```
Map<Class<? extends ArgType<T>, ArgType<T>>
```

is not a valid statement because T is not defined. Is there a way to make this map work without casting a lot, or is there a better way to do this entirely?

Comment: I'm not sure that generics will help you here. Reflection perhaps.

Comment: The basis is that when a command is being resolved, the first thing that happens is a giant list of:
int arg1 = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
double arg2 = Double.valueOf(args[1]);
Player player = Players.getByName(args[2]);

Instead I want to have those preprocessed, as such, i figured I would need generics of <Integer, Double, Player>

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this with generics without casting. Effectively, what you've got here is a variant of the typesafe heterogeneous container pattern, as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2287460/27358), only it's a typesafe heterogeneous argument list, not a container.

For what it's worth, if you didn't mind switching languages you could look into Scala [tuples](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-tuple-examples-syntax), which are basically the typesafe generic list you're looking for. Even Scala under the hood has a million (well, 22) `Tuple` implementation classes, though, `Tuple1[T]`, `Tuple2[T1, T2]`, `Tuple3[T1, T2, T3]` etc.